# Evaluate time spent in each step of pyspark ETL package/application

Tags: logging, pyspark

I am trying to get execution time of each step in pyspark application, lets say we devide the ETL package in steps:

1. read source and create a dataframe:

```
df: DataFrame = spark.read.format(self.format).load(path=path)
df_rel: DataFrame = spark.read.format(file_format).load(path)
```

2. Next step is doing some transformation:

```
df: DataFrame = df.filter(col("col1").isin(a_list))
df: DataFrame = df.join(df_rel, on='col2', how='inner')
grouped_df: DataFrame = df.groupBy(*b_list).count()
```

3. write dataframe:

```
df.write.format(format).mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").save(path=path, partitionBy=partition_column[0])
```

Now in above scenario, I want to know the time spent on joining two dataframes and also groupby - since spark does lazy evaluation it's not possible to simply log timestamp before and after the step. One way could be to print/show the dataframe 1st record to force spark to execute a step - but I am looking for a more elegenat way to do it (without doing any print/show). Have anyone used any library to do so or any other solution(s)?

I tried keeping a print statement for 1st entry of dataframe before and after groupby (lets say) but print also takes its time and not very nice way if I have capture timing for more steps!

Comment: After each step materialize the dataframe with. `df.cache.foreach(lambda x: x)` . This will materialize the dataframe. So after each dataframe, materialize it and time the block.